# Replacing a character in a string with a set of two possible characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, permutation

```
a = ["0$%","0%%%","0$%$%","0$$"]
```

The above is a corrupted communication code where the first element of each sequence has been disguised as 0. I want to recover the original and correct code by computing a list of all possible sequences by replacing 0 with either $ or % and then checking which of the sequences is valid. Think of each sequence as corresponding to an alphabet if correct. For instance, "$$$" could correspond to the alphabet "B".

This is what I've done so far

```
    raw_decoded = []
    word = []
    for i in a:
        for j in i:
            if j == "0":
                x = list(itertools.product(["$", "%"], *i[1:]))
                y = ("".join(i) for i in x)
    for i in y:
        raw_decoded.append(i)
    for i in raw_decoded:
        letter = code_dict[i] #access dictionary for converting to alphabet
        word.append(letter)
   return word
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is not clear if you are asking about how to produce the replacements or about checking the validity of the sequence. For the late, you should provide more info about how that can be computed.

Comment: itertools.product

Comment: Hi @FadeIn the point is, please show what you've tried, then we can try to adjust what you have. If there's no evidence that you've even made an attempt, then it looks like you're just trying to get people to do it for you, which won't often draw a positive response.

Comment: Alright, I've added what I've done so far.

Comment: Is the 0 present only in the first character of each string?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, perhaps you could add a desired output. What I got from your question could be solved in the following way:

```
b = []
for el in a:
   if el[0] == '0':
       b.append(el.replace('0', '%', 1))
       b.append(el.replace('0', '$', 1))
   else:
       b.append(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
output  = []

for elem in a:
    replaced_dollar = elem.replace('0', '$', 1)
    replaced_percent = elem.replace('0', '%', 1)

    # check replaced_dollar and replaced_percent

    # and then write to output

    output.append(replaced_...)
```